# Не получается сделать миграцию в джанго на МакОС

Tags: python, django

Я работаю в проекте на Джанго на своей ветке. Написал изменения в модели БД и хочу сделать команду `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, однако выдаётся ошибка `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.signals' has no attribute 'post_syncdb'`. У меня стоит версия 4.0.3, в которой этот сигнал не используется, однако в проекте он есть, что не позволяет мне выполнить команду. Какие возможны выходы из данной ситуации, чтобы сделать миграцию?

Мои модели:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_default_pk(cls):
        obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            name='Без категории',
            position=99
        )
        return obj.pk


class Shop(models.Model):
    parser = models.ForeignKey(
    Parser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('shop parser'), related_name='shops')
    name = models.CharField(_('shop name'), max_length=128)
    domain = models.CharField(_('domain'), max_length=128)
    active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('position'), default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_name_category',
                             default=Categories.get_default_pk())

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', 'name')
        verbose_name = _('shop')
        verbose_name_plural = _('shops')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Ну тут два варианта. Либо использовать post_migrate, либо откатиться на более старую версию django.

Comment: А виртуальное окружение тут поможет?

Comment: Устанавливайте именно ту версию Django, под которую изначально написан проект. Ну или если вы хотите использовать последнюю версию, то придётся исправлять весь код для соответствия этой новой версии, и скорее всего одним лишь post_migrate дело не ограничится

Comment: Виртуальное окружение поможет.

Comment: В проекте присутствует докер. Как можно применить миграции через него?